# Xcode 6.3 INDENTATION Causing ARC SEMANTIC ERROR?

Tags: ios, xcode

> Xcode edit -> structure -> re indent

causing compile time ARC semantic errors?
This started happening after Xcode was updated to the latest version. Any idea if this is a bug?

This happened to the Objective-C code Viewcontroller

Comment: Show the line with the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with "invisible" characters quite often hidden in my white spaces, simply erasing the white spaces and putting white spaces/tabs instead often resolved the issue for me.

Now I'm just stating what my situation was, it could be completely different for you.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned as a solution yet it DID NOT work.Any way thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yeah it was a long shot. Could you show the exact line where the error triggers please? with a bit of code above.

Comment: The solution was Deleting the file and  recreating the controller.And not to reindent objective c unless the bug is fixed